# Underscore.js: Combining two arrays with objects using a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I have 2 arrays with objects:

```
first = {
a:false,
b:false,
c:false,
d:false
}
second = {
a:true,
c:true
};
```

I want to get:

```
third = {
a:true,
b:false,
c:true,
d:false
}
```

I'm using underscore and jQuery.
I tried `_.union` but it returns an array with all the indexes of a&b.

Comment: Looks like you know what you want to do, I suggest you start doing it. Come back when you have code to ask a question about.

Comment: Obviously I posted the questions after research and effort... Just tried to keep the question as simple as possible...

Comment: use third = _.union(first, second) http://underscorejs.org/#union

Comment: @kenny, tried that, returns an array with all the indexes of a&b.

Comment: @SharonHaimPour *Obviously*, you did not post that question after you did research. It's utterly impossible to post this kind of question after having done research. Not including any code or any information what you tried and why it didn't work ist not "keeping it simple".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your're looking for underscore's [`defaults`](http://underscorejs.org/#defaults) function

```
var third = _.defaults(second, first);

// Object {a: true, b: false, c: true, d: false}
```

Comment: Its not proper solution is it answer you required @Sharon Haim Pour. This function keeps default values of b and adds keys that are not present in b but are present on a

Comment: I think you want ORing of keys within two objects

Comment: @Kenny - there's no indication that he wants to OR the values. This does the job.